# How can I convert SEC EDGAR Form 13F into Excel?

Tags: discussion

Why was [How can I convert SEC EDGAR Form 13F into Excel?](https://superuser.com/q/1524399/1036833) unilaterally closed? Prof David Postill wrote

> Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help others answer the question.

But how doesn't my question focus on just one problem?

Comment: You are also asking asking for software. That is off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from "I found some website on quora", which is of itself quite meaningless, you do not show any evidence of effort, awareness or goal of the task that you are trying to achieve.

- what have you tried?
- what programs are you using or have available? (Apart from Excel)
- what do you want it to look like?
- what are the expected results?
- what are you actually expecting to achieve or do with the resultant output? (This can be important as it may affect how you use the tools or what outputs you need)

I did leave a comment asking what you had tried and what problems you had but was ignored. If those questions had been answered then it may be that your question could have been reopened days ago, possibly within hours of the closure.

You have "one problem" but no focus on actually solving it.